# How to join list of strings and write to csv file?

Tags: python

I have a list containing source code lines as follows:

```
item1: with open('a.txt', 'a') as fd:
item2: fd.write(a)
```

I want to join them together like:

```
with open('a.txt', 'a') as fd\nfd.write(a)
```

And write this line into a csv column. But when I try to write it, the writer itself separate each line by new line character and saves as :

```
with open('a.txt', 'a') as fd
  fd.write(a)
```

Here is my code:

```
column_2 = [with open('a.txt', 'a') as fd: , fd.write(a)]
column_2 = [with open('a.txt', 'a') as fd: , fd.write(a)]

with open('./dataset/data.csv', 'a', ) as fd:
    field_names = ['column 1', 'column 2']
    writer_object = writer(fd)
    a  = '\n'.join(column_1)
    b = '\n'.join(column_2)
    my_data = [a, b]
    writer_object.writerow(my_data)
```

Thanks.

Comment: `\n` is a new character. The writer writes a new character correctly. Is your visualizer that interprets the `\n` and shows it to you as different lines.

Comment: Where is your actual code that makes a CSV?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you have a \n character? That should create a new line...

Comment: @OneCricketeer I added the code.

Comment: That code doesn't run since `column_1` and `column_2` variables are not defined. Refer [mcve]

Comment: Those are source codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the backslash i.e. `\\n` to prevent the character being treated as a newline.

Comment: what if I want to read it again with new lines? exactly like it was before writing.

Comment: Got it, I should use ```stringName.split('\\n')```